# MVC beginner best practice

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, database, security

I've just started creating my first MVC website; what's the best practice to prevent hacking on my (site as cross site, SQL injection, etc.)?

I'm worried about uploading the site without security, I've encountered an actual injection before using cross site injection. How can I protect the site, can I encrypt the source asp page HTML design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like `Entity Framework` or `NHibarnate` to prevent SQL injections. That are very powerfool tools for working with database.

Other security questions you must solve as other frameworks too.For ASP. NET MVC I find some article here, take a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx)

For cross domain you can probably generate key for every request and store that in `Session` and then check with that generated key.

Comment: what about cross site injection and other types

Comment: I've edited my answer check it.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this [getting started with MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3) guide, it covers both MVC3 and EntityFramework, there are also some notes on security considerations.